# namespace issue in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

```
XmlElement xmlElementSAPD = xmlDocument.CreateElement("SAPD");
root.AppendChild(xmlElementSAPD);

xmlElementSAPD.AppendChild(XmlFunctions.GetXMLElement(xmlDocument, "smu", dr.GetString("sma").Trim()));
```

The c# code above creates XML below.

```
<SAPD>
<smu>123</smu>
</SAPD>
```

How can I change the code above so that I can get

```
<ns0:SAPD>
<ns0:smu>123</ns0:smu>
</ns0:SAPD>
```

Anyone? How can I add ns0: in xml nodes?

Comment: Your example XML is not valid. It does not define the `ns0` prefix.

Comment: Which namespace corresponds to the "ns0" prefix? You can only have a prefix which is mapped (via a `xmlns:ns0` declaration) to a namespace either in this node, or any of the parent nodes of the element.

Comment: this is not the whole code. ns0 is already defined pointing to a url where schema is. sma value from the database is outputting 123 value. if I use <"ns0", "SAPD"> I get <ns0 xmlns="SAPD"> I don't want xmlns written on my node output. All I want is <ns0:SAPD>

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the namespace to your xml document.

Just to give you an idea have a look at the below

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  
XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
schema.Namespaces.Add("ns0", "http://www.sample.com/file");
doc.Schemas.Add(schema);
```

Comment: I have already defined this thing. I am confuse about  ns0: on each node of xml. Can't get rid of <ns0 xmlns="SAPD">. All I want is <ns0:SAPD>

Answer (score 0):

You prefix ns0 needs to be mapped with a namespace else the xml would not be valid.

Assumning ns0 is mapped to `http://tempuri.org` the below code can be used:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement sapd= doc.CreateElement("ns0","SAPD","http://tempuri.org");
        XmlElement smu = doc.CreateElement("ns0", "smu", "http://tempuri.org");
        smu.InnerText = "123";
        sapd.AppendChild(smu);
        doc.AppendChild(sapd);
        doc.InnerXml.ToString();
```

Comment: you code doc.CreateElement("ns0","SAPD","http://tempuri.org"); is producing <ns0:SAPD xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org">.  But I do not want that.  All I want is  <ns0:SAPD>

Comment: @user680865 You have to have the namespace defined somewhere, if you don't want it on the SAPD node, then it has to go on a parent node.  Your example xml doesn't have a parent node, so it has to go on the SAPD node.